How to prevent Import-Csv ignores empty lines?
Background
I have a CSV file that contains both empty line and line breaks in cells like this:

Richard Roe
Mary Major
"Alex Smith
Betty Brown
Chris Clark"

"Betty Brown
Donna Davis
Edward Evans"

Alex Smith

"Richard Roe
Mary Major"


I am trying to write a PowerShell script to read this CSV file and get the following result (insert the name of their department in the list):

"Legal
Richard Roe"
"Accounting
Mary Major"
"R&D
Alex Smith
Betty Brown
Design
Chris Clark"

"R&D
Betty Brown
Design
Donna Davis
Edward Evans"

"R&D
Alex Smith"

"Legal
Richard Roe
Accounting
Mary Major"


Problem
When you read the CSV file with Import-CSV, it ignores the empty lines like this:
PS C:\tmp> Import-Csv -Header Names .\NamesList.csv

Names
-----
Richard Roe
Mary Major
Alex Smith...
Betty Brown...
Alex Smith
Richard Roe...


PS C:\tmp>

What I expected is:
Names
-----

Richard Roe
Mary Major
Alex Smith...

Betty Brown...

Alex Smith

Richard Roe...

You can switch to Get-Content to read the CSV, but it seems difficult to process the line breaks in the cell.
Question
Is there any way to prevent Import-Csv ignores empty lines?
Edit
Department-Name mappings in the another CSV file like this:
Legal,Richard Roe
Accounting,Mary Major
R&D,Alex Smith
R&D,Betty Brown
Design,Chris Clark
Design,Donna Davis
Design,Edward Evans


where are the departments coming from? can you provide the list?

Import-Csv doesn't have this option but you can work your way around it by reading line by line and parsing the content. It requires a bit of work though.
Assuming the file look exactly like you have shared in your question, something like this approach might work:
function Read {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $Header
    )

    $Path = Convert-Path $Path -ErrorAction Stop
    $sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
    $startQuote = $false

    foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($Path)) {
        if ($line.StartsWith('"')) {
            $startQuote = $true
            $sb = $sb.AppendLine($line.TrimStart('"'))
            continue
        }

        if (-not $startQuote) {
            [pscustomobject]@{ $Header = $line }
            continue
        }

        if ($line.EndsWith('"')) {
            $startQuote = $false
            $sb = $sb.Append($line.TrimEnd('"'))
            [pscustomobject]@{ $Header = $sb.ToString() }
            $sb = $sb.Clear()
            continue
        }

        $sb = $sb.AppendLine($line.TrimStart('"'))
    }
}

$names = Read .\NamesList.csv -Header Names
$names

This will output an array of objects like the one you're expecting:
Names
-----

Richard Roe
Mary Major
Alex Smith…

Betty Brown…

Alex Smith

Richard Roe…

Then you can prepend the Departments by updating the objects by index. It's unclear where these are coming from, if we had this information the these could be prepended earlier for a more efficient approach:
$names[1].Names = "Legal`n$($names[1].Names)"
$names[2].Names = "Accounting`n$($names[2].Names)"
$names[3].Names = "R&D`n$($names[3].Names)"
$names | ConvertTo-Csv # <= This for demo, it should be `Export-Csv` instead

Then the resulting CSV would look like what you are expecting:
"Names"
""
"Legal
Richard Roe"
"Accounting
Mary Major"
"R&D
Alex Smith
Betty Brown
Chris Clark"
""
"Betty Brown
Donna Davis
Edward Evans"
""
"Alex Smith"
""
"Richard Roe
Mary Major"


You don't actually need the empty lines from the input CSV for processing. It is only a visual thing. The grouping is already done by putting multiple names into a single quoted field. So just process the input data while ignoring the empty lines and add them back in the output CSV.
This is a simple reproducible example using ConvertFrom-Csv and ConvertTo-Csv, but you can replace them by the Export- cmdlets, the behavior should be the same.
For simplicity I've ignored the fact that you have multiple departments assigned to some groups, but I hope it will be enough to get you started.
$names = ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Names @'

Richard Roe
Mary Major
"Alex Smith
Betty Brown
Chris Clark"

"Betty Brown
Donna Davis
Edward Evans"

Alex Smith

"Richard Roe
Mary Major"
'@

$departments = 'Legal', 'Accounting', 'R&D', 'R&D', 'R&D', 'LEGAL'

$namesWithDeps = foreach( $i in 0..$($names.Count - 1) ) {

    # Output empty field
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Names = '' }

    # Join department and names
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Names = $departments[$i] + [Environment]::NewLine + $names[$i].Names }
}

$namesWithDeps | ConvertTo-Csv

Output:
"Names"
""
"Legal
Richard Roe"
""
"Accounting
Mary Major"
""
"R&D
Alex Smith
Betty Brown
Chris Clark"
""
"R&D
Betty Brown
Donna Davis
Edward Evans"
""
"R&D
Alex Smith"
""
"LEGAL
Richard Roe
Mary Major"


You might use the PSParser.Tokenize Method for this:
$NameList = Get-Content -Raw .\NamesList.csv
[System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize($NameList, [ref]$null) | Format-Table

Yields:
Content                     Type Start Length StartLine StartColumn EndLine EndColumn
-------                     ---- ----- ------ --------- ----------- ------- ---------
…                        NewLine     0      1         1           1       2         1
Richard                  Command     1      7         2           1       2         8
Roe              CommandArgument     9      3         2           9       2        12
…                        NewLine    12      1         2          12       3         1
Mary                     Command    13      4         3           1       3         5
Major            CommandArgument    18      5         3           6       3        11
…                        NewLine    23      1         3          11       4         1
Alex Smith…               String    24     36         4           1       6        13
…                        NewLine    60      1         6          13       7         1
…                        NewLine    61      1         7           1       8         1
Betty Brown…              String    62     38         8           1      10        14
…                        NewLine   100      1        10          14      11         1
…                        NewLine   101      1        11           1      12         1
Alex                     Command   102      4        12           1      12         5
Smith            CommandArgument   107      5        12           6      12        11
…                        NewLine   112      1        12          11      13         1
…                        NewLine   113      1        13           1      14         1
Richard Roe…              String   114     24        14           1      15        12

